# Google Onhub API?

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to create an API for the Google Onhub router, but when I sniff my phone's network traffic it doesn't send to the router but to a google server IP and when I try to connect to the IP I timeout, any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 2):

An API already exists for the Google OnHub. Documentation is sparse, but the known URLs at present are as follows:

- http://onhub.here/api/v1/status
- http://onhub.here/api/v1/diagnostic-report
- http://onhub.here/api/v1/welcome-mat
- http://onhub.here/api/v1/connected-devices
- http://onhub.here/api/v1/get-attestation-information
- http://onhub.here/api/v1/get-endorsement-information

Comment: Can anyone share with me how the responses look like?

Comment: @Youda008 Not on here, no. GitHub is your best bet. Some possible starting places: https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/e1c03b87fee6236c71e4fefcb1ff73a9 and https://github.com/olssonm/google-wifi-api

Answer (score 1):

I am actually working on something that describes exactly what you said.
What you are looking for is the 'Google Home Foyer' API. It's a private service that's only used by Google's apps.

I am documenting it [here.](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7490211/SzzdD1pF?version=latest) It's still in beta, however. I'm also working on an actual desktop client for it [here.](https://github.com/AngeloD2022/OnHubDesktop)